# Ceasar Shift and writing to a file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to write to a new file (create a new file), and I want everything that is shown in the command console (the 26 shifts) when the program runs to all be shown in the new file. However, when I use `file.WriteAllText()` it overwrites each shift and then only shows the 26th shift in the new file I create.

```
using System; 
using System.IO;
namespace ceasarAssignment
{
    public class caesarShift
    {
        public static void Main()
        { 
            string file = @"text.txt", // Name of the file that is being read     from
            encrypted = File.ReadAllText(file), // Reading the file
            decrypted = " ";
            char character = '0';
            int shift = 0;

            encrypted = encrypted.ToUpper(); // Puts the string into uppercase

            char[] alph = new char[26] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',     'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W',     'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
            // The array above is the alphabet (26 characters)
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted text: \n{0}", encrypted);
            //Shows the encrypted text before it is decrypted

            for (int i = 0; i < alph.Length; i++) //adds a counter so that this          for loop will repeat until it has happened 26 times     
            {
                decrypted = "";
                foreach (char c in encrypted) 
                {
                    character = c;// each letter in the file is now defined as a     'character'

                  if (!char.IsLetter(c)) {
                        decrypted += c;
                        continue;
                    }
                    shift = Array.IndexOf(alph, character) - i; //searchs the     array for the character then minuses the counter to add the correct shift 
                    if (shift <= 0)
                        shift = shift + 26;// if the character is at the     beginning of the array go to the end

                    if (shift >= 26)
                        shift = shift - 26;// if the character is at the end of     the array go to the beginning


                    decrypted += alph[shift];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n Shift {0} \n {1}", i+1, decrypted); //Shows     the decrypted code for each 26 shifts
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the code with file.WriteAllText() ? You need to provide all the information relevant to the problem.

Comment: I've placed it  where I put it before, i just got rid of it since it wasn't working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `File.AppendAllText(path, appendText)`

`File.WriteAllText()` will overwrite the file each time the loop is run

Comment: Is there a way to make it so when the text goes into the new file there is a new line after each time the loop is run?

Comment: You can add a newline character at the end of your string that is printed. Try Environment.NewLine or maybe "\n"

Comment: I don'tget how I would do that in this code, since it isn't just a console.WriteLine() that is being printed its a loop, so I am unsure where I would put the /n

Comment: You need to append it to the decrypted string after adding all of the decrypted letters to it but before you write the string to the file. Try decrypted += Environment.NewLine; or  decrypted += "\n";